# Browser-sync serve command with different port

Tags: javascript, gulp

I want to try using gulp and I've made a simple project similar to this [example](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/server-with-livereload-and-css-injection.md)
what I want to do is to serve the project using different port, I've tried to follow this [costum-port example](https://github.com/vohof/gulp-livereload/blob/master/examples/custom-port.js)

and my gulpfile.js looks like this :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
var reload = browserSync.reload;

// watch files for changes and reload
gulp.task('serve', function() {
  livereload.listen(1234);

  browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'app',
    }
  });

  gulp.watch(['*.html', 'styles/**/*.css', 'scripts/**/*.js'], {cwd: 'app'}, reload);
});
```

I also try to add port in `server :{porrt : 9999, baseDir:'app'}`
but the result end up with the default port which is 3000.

Is it possible to change the port? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use both `browser-sync` and `gulp-livereload`?

Comment: Hmm still new here, I thought  `gulp-livereload` will change the port ? so I use that.

Comment: You mean BrowserSync different port

Comment: @BenRacicot Yup yo're right. Back then I don't know about it. You could have improve the question though. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `port` [option](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-port).

```
browserSync({
    port: 9999,
    server: {
      baseDir: 'app',
    }
  });
```

`port` is a direct option of BrowerSync, not a sub-option under `server` option.

Answer (score 3):

Use ui object of browser-sync option for changing default port

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
var reload = browserSync.reload;

// watch files for changes and reload
gulp.task('serve', function() {
  livereload.listen(1234);

  browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'app',
    },
   port: 8080
  });

  gulp.watch(['*.html', 'styles/**/*.css', 'scripts/**/*.js'], {cwd: 'app'}, reload);
});
```

Comment: it only change the port of the UI of browserSync, what I want is the local port when serve in the browser

Comment: You can use the port option of changing the serving port.